# Don't hide the tooltip when cursor is inside it in Highcharts chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to make my tooltip stay visible when hovering inside it, but as soon as I move towards a new series point then it will show the tooltip for that point instead.

I can't seem to find a way to do this, even if I create my custom tooltip using `new Highcharts.Tooltip()` (which I haven't done in this example). Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Here's my current tooltip:

```
 highcharts.config.tooltip = {
    enabled: true,
    useHTML: true,
    hideDelay: 0,
    formatter: function (e) {

        ... Lots of HTML ...

        return html;
    }
};
```

Comment: So you want to achieve something similar to this example? http://jsfiddle.net/0u66owj4/1/

Comment: No, that example actually just shows the problem.

Comment: What about a solution where your chart has a text block in a fixed position within the chart that updates as you move over points?

Comment: Maybe you can use custom tooltip, added manually? Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/3f2vejah/1/

Comment: Another possible option could be to use the standard tool tip, but capture the point click event to open a dialog or popup with the appropriate data, or populate a table or div already on the page.

Comment: You can use dataLabels instand of tooltop, check out this example: http://jsfiddle.net/ujmxxf03/10/